# How to link the related data in the separate RDBMS databases of the micro-services in a typical micro-services architecture?

Tags: java, design-patterns, microservices

Let us say that I am designing an e learning portal where in a user can choose the courses he wishes to take and then do the payment online and then he/ she can use the courses.So I have modules like 1) Courses 2) Payments 3) User management. I choose to design 3 separate microservices i.e. a) Courses b) Payments and c) User management based on the domain. Now if this system was a monolith then we could have used a foreign key and would have linked the user , courses and payments tables for relating the data. Now since these 3 are different micro-services and will have its own databases, then how is the data linked together? i.e. If I want to relate that a particular user 'X' has enrolled to 'A','B','C' courses?

Answer (score 0):

The micro service consumer of another other micro service can store identifiers of a specific external resource and relate it **logically** to its own resources in its database (RDBMS or any DB type).
That is not a database constraint relation but if this constraint is a have to, you can of course add some check about its presence and its consistency.

Supposing that the relation between the micro services be :

```
User Management  ->  Courses
                uses
```

The User Management could store resource identifiers of Courses resources associated to Users.
In this way you have a way to join the data of two domains in a specific way.
If the other dependency way is necessary ( Courses ->   User Management), nothing prevents you to perform the same logical.

Not your question but important consequence of data relationship between micro service : data update of external resources have to be handled. Pull, push ? With or without cache ?  It essentially depends on your use cases.

Comment: Thanks. The use cases be like 1) User selects the courses wanted and adds to the cart. 2) User does the payment for the courses chosen .3) Whenever the user logs in then he/she should be able to view the courses which he/she has bought. Thus taking an example of #3 we need to have a relation between Users --> Courses . Can you please be a little specific about how is this relation maintained by the consumer at a low level? Can you share some links which explains this if possible?